# Spring Batch cannot Load the JobBuilderFactory in my integration test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a configuration that successfully works and loads cell line data and publishes to various recipients in a cell line topic. It works fine, but when I try to load the JobLauncherTestUtils and JobRepositoryTestUtils, I get an error which says that the JobBuilderFactory is not found.  As you will see from my configuration, I do load the JobBuilderFactory and StepBuilderFactory using Lombok which delegates to Spring. Like I said all that works fine but the test
Here is the test configuration yaml file

application-test.yml

```
    spring:
        sql:
         init:
            schema-locations: classpath:db/migration
            platform: derby



        jobmeta-ds:
            datasource:
              driver-class-name: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
              url: jdbc:derby:support/jhhmeta;create=true
              password:
              jndi-name: false

       cell-datasource:
          datasource:
           driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
           url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
           password:
           jndi-name: false
```

Here are the datasources:

```
      // CellDbConfig class

       @Configuration
       public class CellDbConfig {

       @Bean
       @ConfigurationProperties("cell-datasource")
       public DataSourceProperties cellLineDataSourceProperties() {
         return new DataSourceProperties();
       }

       @Bean(name = "cellDataSource")
       public DataSource cellDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource dataSource = cellLineDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .build();
       return dataSource;
      }

       @Bean(name = "cellJdbcTemplate")
       public JdbcTemplate cellJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("cellDataSource") DataSource cellDatataSource) {
       return new JdbcTemplate(cellDataSource);
       }
     }
```

Here is the other datasource for the JobRepository datasource configuration

```
        @Configuration
        public class JobRepoMetadataDbConfig {
    
        @Primary
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("jobmeta.datasource")
        public DataSourceProperties jobMetadataProperties() {
            return new DataSourceProperties();
        }
    
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "jobMetaDataSource")
        public DataSource dataSourceJobMeta() {
            DataSource dataSource = jobMetadataProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(BasicDataSource.class)
                    .build();
            return dataSource;
        }
    
        @Bean(name = "jobMetaJdbcTemplate")
        public JdbcTemplate jobMetaJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("jobMetaDataSource") DataSource jobMetaDataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(jobMetaDataSource);
        }
    
    }
```

Here is the Spring Batch specific configuration, i.e. JobRepository etc.

```
       @Configuration
       @EnableBatchProcessing
       @RequiredArgsConstructor
       public class JobRepoConfig {
    
        @Qualifier("jobMetaDataSource")
        final DataSource jobMetaDataSource;
    
        @Bean
        AbstractPlatformTransactionManager jobTransactionManager() {
            return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactory() throws Exception {
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(jobMetaDataSource);
            factory.setTransactionManager(jobTransactionManager());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory;
        }

    
        @Bean
        public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(jobMetaDataSource);
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(jobTransactionManager());
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDatabaseType(DatabaseType.H2.getProductName());
            return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public SimpleJobLauncher launchAppJobLauncher() throws Exception{
            SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
            simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
            return simpleJobLauncher;
        }
    
    }
```

Here is the KafkaProducer configuration that publishes the cell line data:

```
        @Configuration
        @Slf4j
        public class ProducerConfig {
    
        @Value("${spring.kafka.template.default-topic}")
        private String cellsTopic;
    
        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<Long, CellVO> kafkaProducerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
            var producerProperties = kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
    
            var sslProperties = kafkaProperties.getSsl().buildProperties();
    
    
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(producerProperties);
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(sslProperties)) {
                props.putAll(sslProperties);
            }
    
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<Long, CellVO> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Long, CellVO> kafkaProducerFactory) {
            KafkaTemplate<Long, CellVO> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<Long, CellVO>(kafkaProducerFactory);
            kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic(cellsTopic);
            return kafkaTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Here is the Spring Batch test class:

```
        @SpringBatchTest
        @SpringBootTest
        @ActiveProfiles("test")
        @Tag("integration")
        @EnableAutoConfiguration
        public class CellCongTest {
    
    
        @Autowired
        private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
    
    
        @Autowired
        private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;
    
    
        @Test
        public void testSuccessfulLoad() throws Exception {
    
        }
    
      }
```

Finally here is the Batch Job itself:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableScheduling
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class CellBatchJobConfig {
    
        final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
        final JobLauncher jobAppJobLauncher;
        final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
        final KafkaTemplate<Long, CellVO> kafkaTemplate;
        final KafkaItemWriteListener kafkaItemWriteListener;
        final static String CELL_LINE_JOB = "CELL_LINE_JOB";
    
    
        @Value("${chunk-size}")
        private int chunkSize;
    
        @Qualifier("cellDataSource")
        final DataSource cellDataSource;
    
    
        @Bean
        public JdbcPagingItemReader<CellVO> cellDataReader(
                PagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider) {
            return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<CellVO>()
                    .name("cellDataReader")
                    .dataSource(cellDataSource)
                    .queryProvider(pagingQueryProvider)
                    .pageSize(chunkSize)
                    .rowMapper(new CellRowMapper())
                    .build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public PagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider() {
            OraclePagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();
            final Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
            sortKeys.put("CELL_ID", Order.ASCENDING);
            pagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
            pagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause(" CELL_ID, CELL_TYPE, SITE, CELL_QUALITY_LINE ");
            pagingQueryProvider.setFromClause(" FROM DCV.CELL_LINES");
            return pagingQueryProvider;
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public KafkaItemWriter<Long, CellVO> kafkaItemWriter() throws Exception {
            KafkaItemWriter<Long, CellVO> kafkaItemWriter = new KafkaItemWriter<>();
            kafkaItemWriter.setKafkaTemplate(kafkaTemplate);
            kafkaItemWriter.setItemKeyMapper(CellVO::getLocationId);
            kafkaItemWriter.setDelete(false);
            kafkaItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
            return kafkaItemWriter;
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public Step loadCellLines() throws Exception {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .<CellVO, CellVO>chunk(chunkSize)
                    .reader(cellDataReader(pagingQueryProvider()))
                    .writer(kafkaItemWriter())
                    .listener(kafkaItemWriteListener)
                    .build();
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public Job cellLineJob() throws Exception {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get(CELL_LINE_JOB)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(loadCellLines())
                    .build();
        }
    
        @Bean("jobParameters")
        JobParameters jobParameters() {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("jobId", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .addDate("date", new Date())
                    .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
            return jobParameters;
        }
    
    
       @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 5 * * *")
        public Job runCellLineJob() throws Exception {
            kafkaItemWriteListener.setItems(new ArrayList<>());
           return jobBuilderFactory.get(CELL_LINE_JOB)
                   .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                   .start(loadCellLines())
                   .build();
        }
    
    }
```

Unfortunately, the test fails with a message that it could not load the application context:

The error is as follows:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherTestUtils':
```

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJob' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ‘cellBatchJobConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

One thing I did try was to inject the job manually but that did not work: I don't even know why it should be able to find the job if it can find the Job in the actual configuration but not in the test

```
@Configuration
class JobLaunchUtilsCellLine {
  
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("cellLineJob")
  Job cellLineJob;
  
  @Bean
  public JobLauncherTestUtils cellLineJobLauncherUtils(){
      JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
      jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(cellLineJob);
      return jobLauncherTestUtils;
  }        

}
```

I then inject it like this in the Spring Batch test, but it doesn't work:

```
 @Qualifier("cellLineJobLauncherUtils")
 @Autowired
 JobLauncherTestUtils cellLineJobLauncherUtils;
```

However, it still complains about JobBuilderFactory bean does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We encountered the same issue when we added a new scheduled job configuration

How it has been addressed:

1. Create the JobLaunchUtils (similar to yours)

```
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobRepositoryTestUtils
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean

class JobSpecConfiguration {
    @Bean
    JobLauncherTestUtils getJobLauncherTestUtils() {
        new JobLauncherTestUtils()
    }

    @Bean
    JobRepositoryTestUtils getJobRepositoryTestUtils() {
        new JobRepositoryTestUtils()
    }
}
```

2. Remove the `@SpringBatchTest` and added the needed configuration in the `@ContextConfiguration`. We're able to solve the bean depenedency issue upon doing this.

```
import org.spockframework.spring.SpringBean
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobRepositoryTestUtils
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import spock.lang.Specification

@DirtiesContext
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [Application, TestConfig])
@ActiveProfiles(['test', 'kafka'])
class SubmitFilesJobSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils

    @SpringBean
    private SomeRepo someRepo = Mock()

    def cleanup() {
        jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions()
    }

    //some unit test that we have
    def "Verify batch run"() {
        given: "At least 1 Open Record"
        def record = defaultData()
        someRepo.findTop1ByStatus(_) >> record

        when: "A batch job has been triggered"
        def jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(BaseJobExecution.getJobParameters(null))

        then: "Job will be completed with at least 1 persisted/processed record"
        2 == jobExecution.getStepExecutions().size()
        jobExecution.getStepExecutions().forEach(stepExecution -> {
            1 == stepExecution.getWriteCount()
        })
        "SOME_JOB_NAME" == jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName()
        "COMPLETED" == jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode()
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig extends JobSpecConfiguration {

        @Override
        @Bean
        JobLauncherTestUtils getJobLauncherTestUtils() {
            new JobLauncherTestUtils() {
                @Override
                @Autowired
                void setJob(@Qualifier("submitFilesJob") Job job) {
                    super.setJob(job)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Successful Unit Test Run using Spock Framework
[image: Unit Test Run]

Comment: Sorry, I discovered that this had been posted after a while. Thank you very much, and really appreciated!